# handling database transactions across web servers

Tags: hibernate, transactions, xa, transactionmanager

we are planning to develop a new application where we have one servlet container and two web services, webservice1 will access database A, webservice2 will access database B. on user action we need to persist data on database A and database B so all operations should be atomic.

currently we are planning to use tomcat, Rest webservice with spring and Hibernate.
to ensure atomicity what mechanisms can be used?

we want to avoid using XA as it needs application server and also it is heavy.

please suggest any alternatives

Comment: you'll need a DBMS that supports 2-phase commit to handle distributed transactions.

Comment: we are using Sybase, does any DBMS provides such mechanisms ?

Comment: a bit of googling revealed that sybase indeed seems to support the 2-phase commit protocol. It makes sense to learn about it, because due to theoretical reasons (see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Generals%27_Problem) not all problems can be resolved automatically. I'd reconsider the design decision, but if there are strong reasons for the design, you'll have to know the downside